# PHP $GLOBALS losing values

Tags: php, global-variables

I'm very new to PHP. For a class assignment, we need to make a Tic Tac Toe game. So far, this is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="input">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
//Display Determinations

//Top Left
if (!ISSET($_POST['submit'])) {
    $GLOBALS['ul_truefalse'] = true;
    $GLOBALS['turn'] = 1;
    $this_happened = "!isset";
}
if (ISSET($_POST['submit'])) {
    $GLOBALS['turn'] = $GLOBALS['turn'] + 1;
    if ($GLOBALS['turn'] == 3) {
        $GLOBALS['turn'] = 1;
    }
}
if ($GLOBALS['ul_truefalse'] == true) {
    $GLOBALS['ul_display'] = "UL";
    if (ISSET($_POST['input']) and $_POST['input'] == "ul" and $GLOBALS['turn'] == 1) {
        $GLOBALS['ul_display'] = "X";
        $GLOBALS['ul_truefalse'] = false;
        $this_happened = "p1 ul";
    }
    if (ISSET($_POST['input']) and $_POST['input'] == "ul" and $GLOBALS['turn'] == 2) {
        $GLOBALS['ul_display'] = "O";
        $GLOBALS['ul_truefalse'] = false;
    }
}

echo "Player " . $GLOBALS['turn'] . ", it's your turn!";
echo $this_happened;
?>


<table border="1" width="40%">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $GLOBALS['ul_display'] ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Here is the output (left side is when the page is loaded, right side is when player 1 enters "ul"): https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaB1E.png

The problem is when `if (!ISSET($_POST['submit'])) {` becomes false, the strings defined in that if statement lose their values, causing the undefined variable errors. I tried storing them in a hidden form box, but it didn't fix the issue. I sent my code to a person from a forum, and he said it worked. Why is this happening? How do I fix this?

Comment: PHP doesn't have persistive global vars. They're always only populated for the current page request. You're looking for sessions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="input">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(!session_id())
    session_start();

//Display Determinations

//Top Left
if (!ISSET($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['ul_truefalse'] = true;
    $_SESSION['turn'] = 1;
    $this_happened = "!isset";
}
if (ISSET($_POST['submit'])) {
    $_SESSION['turn'] = $_SESSION['turn'] + 1;
    if ($_SESSION['turn'] == 3) {
        $_SESSION['turn'] = 1;
    }
}
if ($_SESSION['ul_truefalse'] == true) {
    $_SESSION['ul_display'] = "UL";
    if (ISSET($_POST['input']) and $_POST['input'] == "ul" and $_SESSION['turn'] == 1) {
        $_SESSION['ul_display'] = "X";
        $_SESSION['ul_truefalse'] = false;
        $this_happened = "p1 ul";
    }
    if (ISSET($_POST['input']) and $_POST['input'] == "ul" and $_SESSION['turn'] == 2) {
        $_SESSION['ul_display'] = "O";
        $_SESSION['ul_truefalse'] = false;
    }
}

echo "Player " . $_SESSION['turn'] . ", it's your turn!";
echo $this_happened;
?>


<table border="1" width="40%">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $_SESSION['ul_display'] ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That wouldn't work. You need to call `session_start()` before any output

Comment: This answer actually worked. Thank you. (I would give you an upvote if I was able to)